# Storing data to use it with Numpy, with automatic title

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a huge data file which has this design:

```
A B C D
2 3 1 2
3 1 3 6
1 5 4 1
```

I want to store this in numpy arrays because i need to do a lot of calculations with them. So i want arrays that look like this, where the names of the arrays are created automatically:

```
A=[2,3,1]
B=[3,1,5]
C=[1,3,4]
D=[2,6,1]
```

Is it possible to automatically generate the names for these arrays?

Comment: do you want as output a dictionnary containing all the arrays? Below a solution with a multidimensinnal array, which should be more convenient than spreading lots of arrays everywhere in the memory without track ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `numpy` structured array with the names of each column taken from the first line of your input using [`genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) and setting `names` to `True`

```
import io
import numpy as np

t=u"""A B C D
      2 3 1 2
      3 1 3 6
      1 5 4 1"""

data = np.genfromtxt(io.StringIO(t),names=True)

print data['A']
# [ 2.,  3.,  1.]

print data['B']
# [ 3.,  1.,  5.]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working but I am not writing that much in python to assure you it's the pythonic way : )

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

names  = content[0].split()


for name in names:
     exec("%s = []"%(name))

for line in content[1:]:
     arr = map(int,line.split())
     i = 0
     for name in names:
         exec("%s.append(%d)"%(name,arr[i]))
         i+=1
```

The arrays names are defined from the first line.